# How to find the branch from commit id

Tags: github, git-commit

So, I am trying to find branch name in which a given commit was made. (`c853d8cf3ae34dae9866b874b96c6529515d7e90`)

I have the parent id and commit id referenced on the git issue.
How can I find that given commit id was pushed in '`x`' branch?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Git: Finding what branch a commit came from](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2706797/git-finding-what-branch-a-commit-came-from)

Comment: GitHub has now as specific way of showing the branch from a commit. See my edit.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

On GitHub specifically, you now can *see* the branch a given commit is part of.
The blog post "[Branch and Tag Labels For Commit Pages](https://github.com/blog/1451-branch-and-tag-labels-for-commit-pages)" details:

> If the commit is not on the default branch, the indicator will show the branches which contain the commit.
>   **If the commit is part of an unmerged pull request, a link will be shown**.

[image: Link to pull request]

> Once the commit makes it to the default branch, any tags that contain the commit will be shown, and the default branch will be the only branch listed.

[image: branch part of commit]

---

Original answer

You can list those branches:

```
git branch --contains <commit>

# in your case
git branch --contains <commit> | grep x
```

More details in "[Git: Finding what branch a commit came from](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2707110/6309)".

Don't forget that a commit can be part of several branches.

Comment: Thanks for the update VonC.The new feature is pretty cool. Finally the feature I always wanted on Git.

Comment: If you want to use it programatically, these options might be helpful: `git branch --no-color --no-column --format "%(refname:lstrip=2)" --contains <commit>`

Comment: Do note that the use of `--format` in the above mentioned tip (as sweet as it is) is only available in git v2.13.2 and later.

Comment: what if there is no branch name there, probably got delete, how can I checkout to it locally?

Comment: @jangorecki you can create a new branch, starting from the commit id. `git switch -c newBranch <commitID>`, using the new `git switch` command: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57066202/6309

Answer (score 7):

Just a cheat.

You can see the branch on the commit detail page of Github like the following:

```
https://github.com/{github_username}/{repo}/commit/{commit_id}
```

Ex: https://github.com/chungth/Laravel-5.2-Bootstrap3-starter-site/commit/f81c13234a9da988613e14e52f752abec5f51997

You can see the current branch name on that page.

Comment: Super useful.  Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

I like  Go to repo in browser.
Click on commits
Enter commit id in search box and hit enter
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nwOWT.jpg)