# Why can I see a commit on GitHub but can't look at it on my local repository?

Tags: git, github

I am trying to do some investigation on the following commit:

https://github.com/dolphin-emu/dolphin/commit/f28cd62519f071dce69efc0bee4b20a849ae3dea

(In particular I was trying to find out if this commit is in the "commit ancestry chain" of any tag/branch.)

When I gitcloned this repository, I can't see this commit.

```
>git show f28cd62519f071dce69efc0bee4b20a849ae3dea
fatal: bad object f28cd62519f071dce69efc0bee4b20a849ae3dea
```

I also tried a couple of things from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3489173/how-to-clone-git-repository-with-specific-revision-changeset), but still couldn't see it.

```
>git fetch origin f28cd62519f071dce69efc0bee4b20a849ae3dea
error: no such remote ref f28cd62519f071dce69efc0bee4b20a849ae3dea

>git reset --hard f28cd62519f071dce69efc0bee4b20a849ae3dea
fatal: Could not parse object 'f28cd62519f071dce69efc0bee4b20a849ae3dea'.
```

What has happened to this commit and why can I see it on GitHub but not in my local repository? Is there any way to inspect it locally?

Comment: have you tried to pull it from the remote repo,if not try to pull the master and see what happens there?

Comment: @LethalProgrammer what do you mean by "pull it from the remote repo", please give the exact command to use, because my question lists the commands I tried and how they didn't work. Also, master is the default branch and so I already have it by means of cloning the repo, i.e. there is nothing to pull.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is essentially a duplicate of [Retrieve specific commit from a remote Git repository](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14872486/1256452) for which [VonC's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30701724/1256452) is essential.  But I was a bit curious so I poked around, and wrote this up.

---

For various reasons both good and bad, the Git transfer protocol used by `git fetch` usually does not allow you to specify raw hash IDs.  (The essential restriction is that it's the *other* Git, the one you call up on the Internet-phone by running *your* Git, that controls the name-to-ID mappings that you are allowed to see.  They *may* allow you to use raw hash IDs, as in [VonC's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30701724/1256452), but that's up to them and requires that they explicitly enable the feature.)

What this means in practice is that to `git fetch` some particular commit, even if you know its hash ID, you must know or discover some *name* from which the commit is *reachable*.  If these were all in your own Git repository, you would do this by running:

```
git branch --contains <hash>
```

and:

```
git tag --contains <hash>
```

to see which branch and/or tag names "reach" the commit, i.e., starting from those branch or tag names while running a graph-walking command like `git log`, eventually the commit you care about would show up.

Of course, the problem with this is that you *don't* have that commit.  It's that *other* Git that has that commit.  So you must convince *them* to do this for you.  You must get *them* to tell you which name or names will reach the commit.  Or ... well, let's save this for a moment.

According to [How to tell which branch a github commit was for?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9360809/1256452) the display page that GitHub shows now *automatically* includes a name that reaches the commit, unless the commit is reachable from the *default* branch.  When I click your link I see no name, which implies that it is on the default branch.  But that contradicts this:

> When I gitcloned this repository, I can't see this commit.

So I tried cloning it myself, and indeed, it is not in my clone either—which tells us that it is *not* in fact on the default branch.  If it were, it would be in the clone, since the clone clones all exposed branches and tags.

In other words, GitHub's claim that we see which branch contains the commit, when we view the page through the web interface, is ... well, maybe not *a lie*, but at least too strong.

#### So where is it?

Now we may wish to bring out the Big Hammer: a *mirror clone*.  A mirror clone is a form of `--bare` clone, where you get no work-tree at all, but it also modifies the `fetch` refspec so that you get *every* reference, not just branches and tags.  (This is a pretty big repository, so I actually just converted my existing clone to a fetch mirror.<sup>1</sup>)  GitHub uses a bunch of unusual references, stored in `refs/pull/` and `refs/reviewable/` name-spaces.  Perhaps our commit is buried in one of these.

Converting the clone to a mirror and re-fetching brought over a lot more commits—there are 6140 "pull request" name-space items and 2557 "reviewable" items—but commit `f28cd62519f071dce69efc0bee4b20a849ae3dea` is *still* not among them.  It is, in fact, nowhere to be found.

There are some more clues here though: it's a revert of another commit, [`d12cc39826791220987b6df2a91cbedaae4d8264`](https://github.com/dolphin-emu/dolphin/commit/d12cc39826791220987b6df2a91cbedaae4d8264), also accessible through GitHub's web interface (click on the commit it claims to revert).  `d12cc39...` is `f28cd62519f071dce69efc0bee4b20a849ae3dea`'s immediate parent as well; and `d12cc39...`, too, does not appear in the mirror clone—but `d12cc39...`'s *parent*, `5d1db5d717d22339b498c24d5a3206743dbe68f1`, *is* in both `master` and `stable`.

So, given that we have `5d1db5d7...` in our clone, but neither `d12cc39...` nor its subsequent revert `f28cd62...`, it seems likely that this is what happened:

- The author wrote a commit and submitted it for review.
- The author realized the commit was wrong and added a revert to the review.
- The author then realized that changing something, then changing it back immediately, is kind of pointless, and *retracted the review*.  There is now *no* name by which these two commits can be reached.
- However, GitHub had already decided to allow web access to the two commits, and has yet to *revoke* said web access to these two no-longer-clone-able (in any way at all) commits.

In the end, then, this means you *cannot* get those two commits into your own repository—but there is no reason to bother; the author has retracted them as the revert was for something that was never added because it was (probably) wrong.

---

<sup>1</sup>In fact, I cheated and used `--fetch-head-ok` to fetch into a non-bare hand-built fake fetch mirror.  You are not supposed to do this; it's not normally a good idea; it's a bit like checking whether the power is on by throwing a lot of sparks.  You might set fire to something if you don't know what you're doing. :-)

Comment: Thanks for your very detailed and interesting explanation. So even though f28cd62 is not in the commit ancestry chain of any branch, the code as of this commit is identical to that in 5d1db5d7, which is in the commit ancestry chain of master branch. (Dolphin (the released software) version 4.0-722 does report itself as being based on hash f28cd62... in the About window, but this is not an issue, as I can just build 5d1db5d7 and it will be identical.)